# Add value of TOP (ALL) to parameter in SSRS report connecting to SSAS cube

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas

I have a simple SSRS report connecting to an SSAS cube that displays all the sales by employee for a day. The report displays correctly and shows me all employees and its sales, in descending order.

But the users don't want to see all the sales; they just want to see the top N. So I added a `Top N` operator filter to the dataset, and the value of that filter (ie. the N) comes from parameter `@TopN` (`Expression: [Sales]`, `Operator: Top N`, `Value: [@TopN]`).

So the current available static values for `@TopN` are 20, 50, 100, and that works correctly; I select "20" in the parameter dropdown and the top 20 sellers are displayed.

To those parameter options, I want to add "Show All", and if they choose that option, then all the employees will be shown. With this option, a user can display the top 20, 50, or 100 sellers, or just display all the sellers.

How would I be able to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: How many sellers is it possible to have?  Why not set the max value at an arbitrarily large number, like 50000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Eric Hauenstein's solution.